# Process Signals & Slots Using a Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I need to be able make a request GET request, which requires the use of signals to process the replies, and return the reply back in a a processed form. I've structured the code as described in [Threading Wihtout the Headache](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/), but when I run the reply is never received or processed.

```
// Set-up request
QNetworkAccessManager* pConnection(new QNetworkAccessManager());
connect(pConnection,
       SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
       this,
       SLOT(process(QNetworkReply*)));
QUrl url;
url.setUrl(HOST);
url.addQueryItem("P1", "Hi");
url.addQueryItem("P2", "Bob");

// Send request
QNetworkRequest request(url);
pConnection->get(request);

// Wait for reply
QThread* pResponce(new QThread(this));
connect(this,
        SIGNAL(processingFinished()),
        pResponce,
        SLOT(quit()));
pConnection->moveToThread(pResponce);
pResponce->start();
pResponce->wait();
pConnection->deleteLater();
pResponce->deleteLater();
return this->processedReply;
```

Obviously I'm missing something, but what? It works when I'm not using the threads (and the deletes), so it's not the URL or server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the main/gui thread receives signals if you don't set up an event loop in the other threads.

> If no event loop is running, events won't be delivered to the object. For example, if you create a QTimer object in a thread but never call exec(), the QTimer will never emit its timeout() signal. Calling deleteLater() won't work either. (These restrictions apply to the main thread as well.)

Source: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/threads-qobject.html

See `QThread::exec()`. **That's why in the example you're linking the QThreadEx class is introduced, and used (not in your code snipplet, though!)...**